# Are free WordPress themes advertised on websites also found in the WordPress.org themes library?

Tags: wordpress

We often see lots of free WordPress themes on websites - e.g. via a search for 'free WordPress themes', one would see results such as '50 free WordPress themes' etc. on a website and recently I saw a site that claimed to have 10,000 free themes. Looking at the current official WordPress library, I can see that there are just over 4,000 themes currently. Most of the free themes I see on other websites online, I also see them in the WordPress library. So for those found on those websites, they are not necessarily 'new' but someone extracted a batch of favorites from the WordPress.org library and posted them on their site to talk about them.

Are there any free WordPress themes available for download on webpages that are NOT found in the official WordPress themes library? If yes, can you please post some links to some of those websites with free themes that cannot be found in the WordPress themes library?

Answer (score 1):

> Are free WordPress themes advertised on websites also found in the WordPress.org themes library?

Not all of them.